# Pie chart with empty middle HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on an MVC webpage, i'm using Kendo for MVC to display some charts. Now, i need a specific chart (image bellow) that i don't seem to find in Kendo. Any ideas how to customize kendo's chart? or are there any JS charts that can be customized like this?
[image]

Comment: The [KendoUI Donut Chart](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/donut-charts/donut-labels) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Philipp, yes thank you. This should be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that will search this. kendo wasn't the best solution as we couldn't add number is the middle. The best solution we could found is a library called Morris.Js  http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/

Comment: FYI, you can add a label/text to the centre of a Kendo Donut chart, they have documentation on it: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/how-to/donut-chart-hole-text.  It's not part of the API, but it is possible.

Comment: @TheDreadPirateStephen i knew it it possible but, imho, a lot of code for something pretty basic. and we also need to change the text in center when hovering over a donut part. Morris had it out of the box, which is nice

Comment: Yep, I don't disagree. Just pointing it out for those who want to stick with one library.